# Transactional replication from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have an Oracle OLTP system and a SQL Server reporting solution. We run nightly stored procedures to extract the data using linked server but it it very slow as it is transferring millions of records. It would be great to have some transactional replication to get this data into our SQL Server environment in a near real time manner for reporting purposes. Has anyone tried this? Without buying an expensive piece of software what would be the best bet?

We've looked into Apache Kafka to capture the changes and apply them to another database but it seems like a high maintenance approach.

If we switched on CDC on the Oracle side could we write a stored procedure to query the CDC table and make the changes?

Is there a simpler approach that we've overlooked?

We only have read access to the Oracle server but it is managed by a third party that could set up something on our behalf.

Comment: The queries used over the linked server connection matter. Bulk copy of anything that changed to local staging tables followed by local insert/update/delete will be much faster than using more complex queries that reference local and over the link tables to pull updates.

Comment: 100% switch on Oracle CDC and use that.

Comment: Oracle CDC has been deprecated and removed in the most recent versions, in favor of Oracle GoldenGate, which is (of course) an extra cost product. That said, GoldenGate can be used to replicate data/transactions between many different database types - including SQL Server - in near real-time.

Comment: The question is quite broad. Self-developed solution will always require high maintenance effort compared to market-ready solution as the latter was already lived this  stage. You may build CDC by yourself with triggers (or even materialized view logs), but this may move your problem to different place: main system slowdown. higher latencies and overhead, because batch operations consume less resources. It really depends on your current ETL setup and why it is so slow as of now. BTW you'll transfer the same (or even more) amount of data in realtime, so the overall speed shouldn't differ much

Comment: I agree - either pay for a OOTB solution that just works, or roll your own and forever be maintaining it (not to mention coming up with some process for capturing deletes)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at https://github.com/OttoGroupSolutionProvider/movex-cdc .
Sometimes used for the same purpose of feeding SQL Server BI system from Oracle OLTP DB via Kafka.